# Posting Json object as parameter with http

Tags: android, json, android-volley, androidhttpclient, android-json

I need to post some data to a server in this format

```
dates: [{...},{...},{...}]
```

So far I have done this

```
for(RepeatEventItem item : selected_dates){
   pEntity.addPart("dates[]", new StringBody(mapper.writeValueAsString(item)));
}
```

and the resulting format is this

```
["{...}","{...}"]
```

how can I get rid of the quotes as the server is expecting JSONObjects in the array not strings

Comment: you are posting several parts. You only need one.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Does this solve issue with the output format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a two dimensional array

```
for(int i = 0; i < selectdated_dates.size(); i++){
    RepeatEventItem item = selected_dates.get(i);
    pEntity.addPart("dates["+i+"][]", new StringBody(mapper.writeValueAsString(item)));
}
```

The result will be in the format you want.